# Google Sheets script - Delete selected cells across sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to create a button that will delete selected cells across 4 sheets. I've searched all over for a script that does this and I cant find one. Im trying to delete cell A2:BC51 across sheet1, Sheet2, Sheet3, Sheet4 with one button. Thanks for your help!

This is the closest I could find to what im looking for:

```
function clearRange() {
  //replace 'Sheet1' with your actual sheet name
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  sheet.getRange('A2:BC51').clearContent();
}
```

Comment: What you have looks correct and like in Excel, I don't think it's possible to create a range across sheets so you'll have to do each Sheet 1 at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function clearRange() {
  var range = "A2:BC51";
  SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sheet1').getRange(range).clearContent();
  SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sheet2').getRange(range).clearContent();
  SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sheet3').getRange(range).clearContent();
  SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sheet4').getRange(range).clearContent();
}
```

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

You could perhaps try.

```
function clearSheets() {
  clearRange('Sheet1');
  clearRange('Sheet2');
  clearRange('Sheet3');
  clearRange('Sheet3');
}

function clearRange(strSheet) {
 //replace 'Sheet1' with your actual sheet name
 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName(strSheet);
 sheet.getRange('A2:BC51').clearContent();
}
```

I've just replaced `'Sheet1'` with a variable called `strSheet` and put `clearRange(strSheet)` so that the sheet name can be passed to the function.

You could also do `clearRange(strSheet, strRange)` so that you can call the function `clearRange('Sheet1', 'A2:BC51');`

it will make it easier to update the code should the range change.

I've not tested this but it might work.